# Given a Date time calculate how many times it will cross a certain hour from now

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a DATE1, for example `31/12/2021 00:09:50`. Giving a specific time `21:00:00`, I need to show how many times between `=NOW()` and DATE1 this time will be crossed.

Answer (score 1):

If DATE1 were in cell A2, and the "specific time" were in B2 this should work:

```
=INT(A2)-TODAY()+(B2>MOD(NOW(),1))-(MOD(A2,1)>B2)
```

It works by just counting how many days it is *between* the date portions, then adding 1 if the specific time is *after* the NOW() time, then subtracting 1 if the time portion of DATE1 were *after* the specific time.

Comment: Thanks for this. I have put into a sheet but had no success with the result. Would you take a look please? Formula on column D and expected result on column E. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ShMtXpvs0prqZlIxOoLW383NeWO3yHQtcozFDn-VjM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Dan-SP the sheet is "view only" so it is difficult to investigate

Comment: @Dan-SP You're missing a piece of the formula, double check that you have it right from this post.

Comment: I will doublecheck. I made another tab and got it by using your idea but in a simpler way. Not sure if its right all the time but "=INT(B4)-TODAY()+if($B$13>D4;0;1)" worked for me

Comment: the TIME reference cell is what i have in there as B2.  Change it to your real time ref cell.

Comment: Could you create a copy and link me ? I cant let you edit without your email